# Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server-2005, login, ssms

Sql server is in Mixed Mode and I changed the user Password through Windows Authentication Mode from Security. After that when I try to connect the server it throw the error

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to AZHAR\SQLEXPRESS.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18452)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18452&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message is thrown then the SQL Server is running on WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION mode. Please change it back to Mixed mode and you will be able to login using SA account.

Comment: but how or from where to change to Mixed mode???

Comment: Open SSMS. Right click on the Instance Name --> Properties --> Security. Select "SQL Server and Windows authentication mode". Click Ok. Restart the instance

Answer (score 0):

My SQL server is of SQL 2005 version and in Mixed authentication mode.Still I got the above error for a windows login. Restarted SQL services and then conenction was successful.